# Как подключиться рабочему репозиторий на GitHub на котором уже есть и запушить свой проект туда?

Tags: github, scrapy

Я Новичок еще и до этого момента работал со своим репозиторием. Сейчас пригласили в компанию. Сейчас стала такая проблема:

1. работал локально - результат готовый проект локально в директории
2. по запросу меня включили На GitHub в репозиторий по данному направлению.
3. мне нужно создать свою ветку в данном репозитории и заПушить проект который я делаю локально.

Как это правильно сделать:
Вариант который я думаю

1. Создать отдельную директорию
2. Клонировать данный репо себе
3. Уже локально создать свою ветку
4. И во вновь созданную директорию перенесли свой проект и потом уже (add, commit, push)

Есть ли другой вариант, что бы не создавать и переносить а сразу подтянуть в папку с проектом подтянуть удаленный репозиторий и после этого создать свою ветку и запушить проект.

Может кто посоветовать, боюсь испортить или что то сделать не правильно

Comment: По моему если первый пункт убрать(создать отдельную директорию), а просто клонировать ,с самого гитхаба, то создаётся директория но это нампример я работаю на визуалСтудио, она все делает.то есть клонировать,потом подтянуть мэин или мастер, те основную ветку и по ней создать новую локально и потом пуш

Comment: Я отдельно изначально не создаю репозиторий.напрмер из дома если подключаюсь к рабочим проектам через девазур(там тот же принцип), то я просто открываю студию, клонировать и сохраняю в папке по умолчанию. И у меня создаётся проект потом я подтягиваю основную ветку (синхронизировать)и на ней создаю свою локальную которую потом пуш

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, но я думаю что если я клонирую в локальную папку где находится проект Scrapy  удаленный репозиторий то мне же прилетит все от туда с ветки main, а я бы не хотел чтоб в моем проекте были файлы которые не относятся к моему проекту. Может я излишне заморачиваюсь ). Сегодня буду тестить посмотрю что получится ).